# It is possible to chain promises in different places than html

Tags: javascript

My apologize for my title. I didn't think of a better title.

I have boot.ini, inside it a promise code that loads several dependencies.

```
var sort            = 0;
var debug           = {{: debug }};
var intervalo_ads   = {{: intervalo_ads }};

const scriptPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  var element       =  document.getElementById('xptraffic_addclass');
  console.log('rodou a promise');
  if (element      == null){ 
    var id_dominio          = {{: id_dominio}};
    const script            = document.createElement('script');
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    script.id               = "xptraffic_addclass";
    script.onload           = resolve(id_dominio);
    script.onerror          = reject;
    script.async            = true;
    script.src              = 'https://server01.xptraffic.com/adclass/'+id_dominio;
  }else resolve(id_dominio);
});
```

**snippet pop**

```
<script id='banner_xptraffic_32_29'>
    window.addEventListener("load",function(event){
        scriptPromise.then((id_dominio)=>{
            Ad36        = new Ad({'id_zona': 36, 'tipo': 'pop', 'formato' : 'PopVideo'});
            Ad36.constructorPromise.then(()=>{
                Ad36.start(Ad36);
            }); 
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

**snippet banner**

```
<script id='banner_xptraffic_32_29'>
    window.addEventListener("load",function(event) {
        scriptPromise.then((id_dominio)=>{
            Ad29  = new Ad({'id_zona': 29, 'tipo': 'banner', 'formato' : '300x250'});
            Ad29.constructorPromise.then(()=>{
                Ad29.start(Ad29);
            }); 
         }); 
     });
</script>
```

These snippets must be run in different locations on the webmaster's website, and there is also no need to load these dependencies multiple times. So, internally, in my pseudo-class, I have treatments to divert the flow if the pseudo-classes are already loaded.

The problem is that the two snippets are executed after the page loads and, as both expect the same promise (load dependencies), they are executed simultaneously and I cannot chain the promises because they will be located far from each other. In different locations of the webmaster's html.

I need a short, uncomplicated code to provide to webmasters. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: If you want to chain them with scripts then the only real solution is attaching the promise to the global object so you can keep chaining from there.

Comment: @MinusFour,  happy with your comment, but I can't do that my friend, because the banner snippet needs to be inserted in the position of the html where it will be shown. Pop and push notifications do not require html location references, and are usually loaded at the end of the html or in the head section due to the page's  speed. This depends on the webmaster and how the cms is implemented. It must be flexible

Comment: Why can't you combine the two scripts into one, for example: having them both initialize in the same `load` event handler? Because if they are both waiting to run until the page is loaded then their position in the document is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you Emiel, if I put window.addEventListener inside scriptPromise, depending on where the webmaster inserts the snippet, there will be no time to load the promise and it will return the Uncaught ReferenceError script: scriptPromise is not defined. In addition, the problem of checking whether all dependencies have been loaded or not remains. Two instances of the AD pseudo-class will continue to run simultaneously.

Comment: When instances Ad36 and Ad29 are executed, there is still no time for the first instance to be completed, causing the second instance to run without being able to verify that the dependencies are being loaded in the first instance of the class and will be loaded again for the second time on the customer’s browser.